# How fast is parseFloat Vs. float ints in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing, parsefloat

I'm getting a huge dataset from a client's internal API. It'll contain a bunch of numerical data of prices such as: $31.23. He gives them to me as `{"spend":"21.23"}` which is fine, but I was concerned that after 1000+ items and running `parseFloat()` on all of those values (on top of graphing them) might be resource heavy on the client's browser.

Has anyone done this?

==Update==

I'm sorry. My question was too vague. My concern was that it's a string and i'm parsing it. My issue was is parseFloat faster than just an int. I.e. is appending `parseFloat("12.12")` to a div faster than simply just appending `12.12` and if so, how much faster.

Comment: Profile it! Make a 1,000 parseFloat calls and time it. Than 100,000.

Comment: @Oscar: You say "just an int" but then you say `12.12`; which is it? Do you mean parsing the *string* "12.12" (to `12`) or skipping parsing altogether?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my work machine (Mac OS X, Intel 2 GHz Core i7), I saw [the following results on jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/parsefloat-vs-parseint):

```
Browser    | parseFloat calls per second
----------------------------------------
Chrome 12  | 5.3 million
Firefox 6  | 21.7 million
IE 8       | 666.9 thousand <- totally unfair, ran on virtual machine
Opera 11   | 5.2 million
```

This is far from an exhaustive survey; but at a rough *minimum* of **over 600 thousand** calls per second (and *that* on a virtual machine), I think you should be good.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That answers my question by far the best. My concern though was is doing something with parseFloat faster than doing something with just a raw int like 12.12 rather than parseFloat("12.12"). see my updated question. Either way, this is 600k calls per second, so it should be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In regard for speed of parseFloat or parseInt **MDN** recommends using the unary operator **+** instead, as in

```
+"12.12"
=> 12.12
```

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number.

Comment: The only side effect of using the `+` instead of `parseFloat` is that it won't work on a string that has a number at the beginning with text as suffix, for example `+"22blah"` result as `NaN` while `parseFloat(22blah)` result as `22`... and BTW I just tested it because I wasn't sure of the output and I would have preferred to use `+` but in my use I can't because of this side effect

Answer (score 0):

you know that `parseFloat()` is based on the browser. So as far as I know the browser could crash after 200 values, could work just fine after 10.000 value.

It depends on how many tabs that browser has, what other scripts is running, how much CPU is free for processing, and of course what browser

if your client uses firefox with 1000 addons it will never run your script smoothly.

just my opinion. If you want to do it nice you should preprocess on a server then display.

Comment: Of course it's based on the browser as all JS is based on the browser. My concern was is it faster to process just ints like 12.12 or parseFloat("12.12") and if there was a difference between it.

Answer (score 0):

Type

javascript:a = +new Date; x = 100000; while (--x) parseFloat("21.23"); alert(+new Date - a);

Into your url bar.

This is the only way to know for sure.

In honesty, you can't answer the question. It depends on the browser, for example, firefox 8 should be faster than 6, and so on.